# deduce that $\cos 6° \cos42° \cos66° \cos78°= \frac{1}{16}$

Tags: trigonometry, self-learning

> Prove that $$4 \cos\theta \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta) \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}+\theta)= \cos 3\theta$$ and deduce that $$\cos 6° \cos42° \cos66° \cos78°= \frac{1}{16}$$

I have proved by using $2 \cos A \cos B= \cos (A+B)+ \cos (A-B) $

But I cant deduce $1/16$

---

P.S. we have to use prove that to deduce $1/16$

Comment: You can apply the identity with $\theta = 18^\circ$ and with $\theta=6^\circ$.

Comment: Interesting product there.  Looks like it can be rewritten as $\sin96^\circ\sin48^\circ\sin24^\circ\sin12^\circ$.

Comment: @Freddy, Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\cos6\cos42\cos66\cos78&=\frac{1}{\cos54\cos18}\left(\cos6\cos54\cos66\right)\left(\cos18\cos42\cos78\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos54\cos18}\frac{\cos18}{4}\frac{\cos54}{4}\\
&=\frac{1}{16}
\end{align}$$