# Proving the trigonometric identity $4\sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)\sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 3 - 4 \cos^2 x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am using the addition and difference formulae for cosine and sine but seem to be getting stuck... somewhere.

Prove that

> $$4\sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)\sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\right)  = 3 - 4 \cos^2 x.$$

Comment: It would help for us to see how far you’ve gotten in this.

Answer (score 3):

We can safely use, [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

$$\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi6\right)\sin\left(x-\dfrac\pi6\right)=\sin^2x-\sin^2\dfrac\pi6=1-\cos^2x-\left(\dfrac12\right)^2=\cdots$$

---

Alternatively

observe that $\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A=\cos A(4\cos^2A-3)$

Use the pattern described in [Proving a fact: $\tan(6^{\circ}) \tan(42^{\circ})= \tan(12^{\circ})\tan(24^{\circ})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir/455573#455573),

to arrive at $4\cos3A=-\cos A\sin\left(A+\dfrac\pi6\right)\sin\left(A-\dfrac\pi6\right)$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
4 \sin(x+\frac{\pi}6)\sin(x-\frac{\pi}6) &= 4 [\sin(x)\cos(\frac{\pi}6)+\cos(x)\sin(\frac{\pi}6)][\sin(x)\cos(\frac{\pi}6)-\cos(x)\sin(\frac{\pi}6)] \\
&=4[\sin^2(x)\cos^2(\frac{\pi}6)-\cos^2(x)\sin^2(\frac{\pi}6)] \\
&=4[\sin^2(x)\frac 34-\cos^2(x)\frac 14] \\
&=3\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x) \\
&=3(1-\cos^2(x))-\cos^2(x) \\
&=3-3\cos^2(x)-\cos^2(x) \\
&=3-4\cos^2(x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$\theta = 2x , \qquad \phi = \frac{\pi}{3}$$
in the sum-to-product identity
$$\cos \theta - \cos \phi = -2 \sin \left(\frac{\theta + \phi}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta - \phi}{2}\right).$$

> Multiplying both sides by $-2$ and then invoking the double-angle identity $\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x - 1$ gives \begin{align}4 \sin \left(x + \frac{\pi}{6}\right) \sin \left(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\right) &= -2\left(\cos 2x - \cos \frac{\pi}{3}\right) \\ &= -2 \left[ 2 \cos^2 x - 1 - \frac{1}{2}\right] \\ &= 3 - 4 \cos^2 x .\end{align}