# Prove that $\tan20^°\tan40^°\tan60^°\tan80^°=3$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\tan20^°\tan40^°\tan60^°\tan80^°=3$

---

\begin{align}
\tan20^°\tan40^°\tan60^°\tan80^°&=\frac{\sin20^°\sin40^°\sin60^°\sin80^°}{\cos20^°\cos40^°\cos60^°\cos80^°} \\
&=\frac{2^4(\sin20^°\sin40^°\sin60^°\sin80^°)^2}{\sin 160^°}
\end{align}

I am stuck here.

Comment: Related  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir?lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use $$\tan{(3x)}=\tan{x}\tan{(60^{\circ}+x)}\tan{(60^{\circ}-x)}$$
and let $x=20^\circ$.

Comment: +1 Very neat. Do you know a slick derivation of your $\tan3x$ equation?

Comment: @almagest Probably insert it into $\frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(3x)}$ and calculate. It seems the most straight-forward, although there might be more elegant solutions out there.

Answer (score 4):

It is the case $m=4$ of the general formula:

$$
\prod_{k=1}^m\tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1} \right)=\sqrt{2m+1}
$$

[See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Identities_without_variables)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Then $$4\cos \alpha \cos (60^{\circ}-\alpha)\cos (60^{\circ}+\alpha)=\cos 3 \alpha$$
Similarly,
$$4\sin \alpha \sin (60^{\circ}-\alpha)\sin (60^{\circ}+\alpha)=\sin 3 \alpha$$

Then $$\tan \alpha \tan (60^{\circ}-\alpha)\tan (60^{\circ}+\alpha)=\tan 3 \alpha$$