# The equation $\tan x = \tan 2x \tan 4x \tan 8x$

Tags: trigonometry

In the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir)  we have the equality
$$\tan 6^{\circ} \tan 42^{\circ} = \tan 12^{\circ} \tan 24^{\circ}$$
which is equivalent to
$$ \tan 6^{\circ} = \tan 12^{\circ} \tan 24^{\circ} \tan 48^{\circ}$$
This means that the equation
$$\tan x = \tan 2x \tan 4x \tan 8x$$
has the solution $x =6^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{30}$.  How to find all the solution of this equation?

Comment: You can repeatedly enforce the identity $\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}$ to express the right hand side as $R(\tan(x))$ where $R$ is a rational function. Then put $\tau=\tan(x)$, solve $\tau=R(\tau)$ for $\tau$, then go back to $x-$ land using $\arctan$ and the fact that the period of $\tan$ is $\pi$.

Comment: $x=0$ is another solution.

Comment: $\tan x\in\left\{0,-\sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{3 \left(5-2 \sqrt{5}\right)}},\sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{3 \left(5-2
   \sqrt{5}\right)}},-\sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{3 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)}},\sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{3 \left(5+2
   \sqrt{5}\right)}},-\sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{5}+2 \sqrt{3 \left(5-2 \sqrt{5}\right)}},\sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{5}+2 \sqrt{3 \left(5-2
   \sqrt{5}\right)}},-\sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{5}+2 \sqrt{3 \left(5+2 \sqrt{5}\right)}},\sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{5}+2 \sqrt{3 \left(5+2
   \sqrt{5}\right)}}\right\}$ are the solutions, these correspond to  $k\pi/30$ with $k=\pm1,\pm7,\pm11,\pm13$

Comment: @Ákos Somogyi: Thank you, that really solves it. I managed to reproduce the calculations with WolframAlpha, not sure I could do it by hand.

Comment: @IITM: That is very interesting. The $\arccos$ of the value is a nice angle it seems.

Comment: I substitued $cos 2x$ in terms of $t$:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282cos2x%2B1%29%2816%28cos2x%29%5E4-16%28cos2x%29%5E2%2B1%29%3D1+solve+for+x and the solutions are same as mentioned by ÁkosSomogyi

Comment: Given the fact that $tan(x) = tan(x+n\pi)$ I would say that there might be more solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factorize the equation as follows
\begin{align}
& \tan x-\tan 2x \tan 4x \tan 8x \\
=& \frac{\sin x \cos 2x \cos 4x \cos 8x-\cos x \sin 2x \sin 4x \sin 8x }
{\cos x \cos 2x \cos 4x \cos 8x }\\
=& \frac{\sin x [\cos 2x \cos 4x \cos 8x-(1+\cos 2x)\sin 4x \sin 8x ]}
{\cos x \cos 2x \cos 4x \cos 8x }\\
 =& \frac{\tan x (\cos 12x -2\sin 2x \sin 8x )}
{\cos 4x \cos 8x }\\
=& \frac{\tan x }{\cos8x} \left( 4 \cos^2 4x-3 -4\sin 2x \sin 4x\right)\\
 =& \frac{\tan x }{\cos8x} \left(16\cos^4 2x +8\cos^3 2x -16\cos^2 2x-8\cos 2x +1 \right)\\
 =& \frac{16\tan x }{\cos8x} \left(\cos^2(2x-\frac{2\pi}3) - \frac12 \cos(2x-\frac{2\pi}3) -\frac14\right)\\
&\hspace{15mm}\times \left(\cos^2(2x+\frac{2\pi}3) - \frac12 \cos(2x+\frac{2\pi}3) -\frac14\right)\\
 =& \frac{16\tan x }{\cos8x} \left(\cos(2x-\frac{2\pi}3) - \cos\frac\pi5\right)\left(\cos(2x-\frac{2\pi}3) - \cos\frac{3\pi}5\right)\\
&\hspace{15mm}\times \left(\cos(2x+\frac{2\pi}3) - \cos\frac\pi5\right)\left(\cos(2x+\frac{2\pi}3) - \cos\frac{3\pi}5\right)\\
\end{align}
where $ \cos\frac{\pi}5 +\cos\frac{3\pi}5 =\frac12$ and $ \cos\frac{\pi}5\cos\frac{3\pi}5 =-\frac14$ are recognized. Then, the full set of the solutions are $x=n\pi,\>n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}3\pm \frac\pi{10}$ and $n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}3\pm \frac{3\pi}{10}
$, or
$$x-n\pi=0, \>\pm \frac\pi{30}, \>\pm \frac{7\pi}{30} , \>\pm \frac{13\pi}{30} , \>\pm \frac{19\pi}{30}
$$

Comment: Very impressive! The factorizations in the last two equalities are not easy to spot.

Comment: @orangeskid - Indeed; took me a while to realize

Comment: @Quanto How did you factorize them?They seem impossible..I mean what's your idea?

Comment: @IITM - Having some experience factorizing trig equations; knowing the partial solutions is also helpful

Comment: @Quanto ok... beautiful factorization though,loved it

Answer (score 4):

$$\tan x=\tan 2x\tan 4x\tan 8x$$

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{\cos 2x}\left(\frac{2\sin 4x \sin 8x}{2 \cos 4x \cos 8x}\right) $$

If $\sin x\neq0$ then,

$$\frac{\cos 2x}{2\cos^2 x}=\frac{\cos 4x - \cos 12x}{\cos 4x + \cos 12x}$$

Now,using componendo-dividendo,

$$\frac{\cos 2x+ 2\cos^2x}{2\cos^2 x-\cos 2x}=\frac{\cos 4x}{\cos 12x}$$

$$ 4 \cos^2 x -1 =\frac{1}{4\cos ^2 4x-3}$$

$$(2\cos 2x+1)(4(2\cos^2 2x -1)^2-3)=1$$

These are the solutions of above equation :[wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282cos2x%2B1%29%2816%28cos2x%29%5E4-16%28cos2x%29%5E2%2B1%29%3D1%20solve%20for%20x)

can someone solve the last equation by hand and edit the answer$?$

also,note that I cancelled some terms like $\cos 4x$,because $\cos 4x=0$ is not in the domain of the equation

Answer (score 3):

$\sin x=0$ is obviously a solution. We will assume for further solutions that $\sin x\neq 0.$

Now:

$$\begin{align}\sin 2x&=2\sin x\cos x\\\sin 4x&=4\sin x\cos x\cos2x\\
\sin 8x&=2\sin 4x\cos 4x\\&=8\sin x\cos x\cos 2x\cos 4x.\end{align}$$

So:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}&=\tan x\\&=\tan 2x\tan 4x\tan 8x\\&=\frac{64\sin^3 x\cos^3 x \cos 2x}{\cos 8x}
\end{align}$$

Cancelling $\sin x\neq 0$ and multiplying both sides by $\cos x\cos 8x$ you get:

$$\begin{align}\cos 8x &= 64\sin^2x\cos^4x\cos 2x\\
&=64(1-\cos^2 x)\cos^4x (2\cos^2x-1)
\end{align}$$

If $u=\cos x$ then:

$$\cos 8x = T_8(n)=128 u^8 - 256 u^6 + 160 u^4 - 32 u^2 + 1$$
where $T_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind, $T_n(\cos x)=\cos nx.$

Together, this means we have the equation:

$$q(u)=256 u^8 - 448 u^6 + 224 u^4 - 32 u^2 + 1=0$$

Wolfram Alpha helps me compute:

$$q(u)=\frac{T_{15}(u)T_1(u)}{T_3(u)T_5(u)}\tag 1$$
(I theorized this equality after playing with the numerical roots of $q.$)

Wolfram verified (1), but it is not really a satisfying answer for “why?”

So, $u=\cos x$ is a root of $q$ if and only if $\cos 15x=0$ but $\cos 5x\neq 0$ and $\cos 3x\neq 0.$

This amounts to $x=\frac{m\pi}{30}$ where $\gcd(m,30)=1.$

So, in $[-\pi,\pi],$ the solutions are $$\begin{align}x=0,&\pm\frac{\pi}{30},\pm\frac{29\pi}{30},\pm\frac{7\pi}{30},\pm\frac{23\pi}{30},\\
&\pm\frac{11\pi}{30},\pm\frac{19\pi}{30},\pm\frac{13\pi}{30},\pm\frac{17\pi}{30}
\end{align}$$

So, other than $0,$ these are the “primitive roots” of $\cos(15x)=0,$ or the $x$ such that $e^{ix}$ is a primitive $60$th root of unity.

Comment: That is a very nice use of the Chevyshev polynomials!

Comment: Factoring the difference (WA) gets $\frac{2( \sin 9x - \sin 3x - \sin 5x)}{ \cos 7x + \cos 9x}$, still needing more work

Comment: Which difference? @orangeskid

Comment: Oh, it's $\tan x - \tan 2x \tan 4x \tan 8x$

Answer (score 1):

*Another solution.*

Consider the equation
$$\tan (2x) \tan (4x) \tan (8x)-\tan(x)=0$$ Let $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$, use the multiple angle formulae and obtain
$$\frac{t^9-28 t^7+134 t^5-92 t^3+t}{t^8-28 t^6+70 t^4-28 t^2+1}=0$$ Discrading the trivial $t=0$,we then face a quartic equation in $u=t^2$
$$u^4-28 u^3+134 u^2-92 u+1=0$$ which can be solved with radicals. The solutions are all positive and the smallest is
$$u=7-2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{15-6 \sqrt{5}}\implies t=\sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{15-6 \sqrt{5}} }$$ and then
$$x=\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{15-6 \sqrt{5}}}\right)$$ At this point, I am stuck; using my 50+ years old pocket calculator
$x=0.1047197551$ which is $\frac \pi{30}$.

But, as @Thomas Andrews answered, there are many other solutions.